# Defining initial values of atoms/particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-states

For a college project I'm simulating the change of magnetization of multiple protons that influence each other.

The goal of my project is to provide a good software structure, so my primary focus was to deal with programming design issues.

For the implementation however, I'll need a lot of physics, which for the most part I have figured out. In my case, I'll have ~100 protons, whose locations are given due to a previous MD-simulation. I'm then calculating the acting magnetic field vector of every proton and calculating the change of its magnetic moment using the 'Bloch-equations'

Right now though, I'm struggling to understand how to define initial values for the state of each proton.

For my simulation to represent the real world as accurate as possible, I figured I'll need to follow the `boltzmann distribution`

So the equation I've found is this: $p = \frac1Z\cdot e^\frac{-E}{k_bT}$ with $Z=\sum_{i=0}^{n}e^\frac{-E}{k_bT}$

Having almost no basics in quantum mechanics I'm struggling to understand how many states a particle, let's say a proton, can have and what the energy then is.

Also, for the example of protons being in an homogeneous magnetic field and thus aligning parallel/anti parallel to the orientation of the external field, I figured there are only two states. What would be the energy for each state then?